# PostgreSQL - Insert records into a table and return the result

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-function

This following code snippet

```
SELECT data.generate_file_data(
   p.file_name,
   p.reference,
   p.extension,
   p.platform,
   p.library,
   p.path,
   p.is_temporary
) x
FROM files.main p;
```

returns a column of records named generate_file_data which looks like this

```
generate_file_data record
(reference, directory, platform, library)
(reference, directory, platform, library)
(reference, directory, platform, library)
(reference, directory, platform, library)
...
```

The results (return type of the generate_file_data() function) are records of the type

```
id integer          directory text        platform text         library text
id                  directory             platform              library
```

Which always returns a single result. I wonder if there is a way to instead split the records to four pieces and put them inside of

```
TABLE(id text, directory text, platform text, library text)
```

so the results will be a table instead of a column of records, kinda like this

```
id integer          directory text        platform text         library text
id                  directory             platform              library
id                  directory             platform              library
id                  directory             platform              library
id                  directory             platform              library
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716) who almost got the answer correct, it seems that CROSS JOIN LATERAL allows us to call the result of the generate_file_data() function for every row and glue it together

```
SELECT x.id, x.directory, x.library, x.platform
FROM files.main p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL data.generate_file_data(
   p.file_name,
   p.reference,
   p.extension,
   p.platform,
   p.library,
   p.path,
   p.is_temporary
) x;
```

Which we do afterwards specify in SELECT which of the columns we do want to return!